# Show difference between conditional expectations is positive

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Suppose I have a continuous random variable $Y$ and a random Bernoulli variable $T$ such that $P(T=1\mid Y)$ is monotonically increasing in $Y$. How can I show that $E[Y\mid T=1]>E[Y\mid T=0]$?

To me, it makes intuitive sense, but I can't prove it mathematically.

Comment: What have you tried mathematically? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad thanks for the link. I'm new here, and I'll make sure to provide more information about what I've tried next time I post a question.

I managed to answer the question by myself, so I've included my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to answer the question myself. I'm including the solution here for other people that might have the same question.

I want to show that the quantity below is greater than $0$.

$=E[Y \mid T = 1]-E[Y \mid T = 0]$

$=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{yP(Y=y \mid T=1)dy}    -\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{yP(Y=y \mid T=0)dy}$

Let $p = P(T=1)$ and $f$ be the PDF of $Y$. Then:

$=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{y\left(\frac{P(T=1 \mid Y=y)f(y)}{p}-\frac{(1-P(T=1 \mid Y=y))f(y)}{1-p}\right)dy}$

$=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f(y)y\left(\frac{P(T=1 \mid Y=y) - p}{p(1-p)}\right)dy}$

$=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f(y)y P(T=1 \mid Y=y)dy}  -   p\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f(y)ydy})$

Let $Z=P(T=1 \mid Y)$. Then:

$=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}(E[YZ]  -   E[Z]E[Y])$

$=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}Cov(Y,Z)$

We know that $Z$ is increasing in $Y$, and the covariance of a random variable and an increasing function of that random variable is always positive ([see reference](https://www.math.tu-dresden.de/sto/schmidt/dsvm/dsvm2003-4.pdf)). Therefore:

$=E[Y \mid T = 1]>E[Y \mid T = 0]$